# Retry a function that returns a Future

Tags: scala, exception, future

Suppose I've got a function `foo` that performs asynchronous computation and returns a `Future`:

```
def foo(x: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = ???
```

Now I'd like to retry this computation `n` times until the computation succeeds.

```
def retryFoo(x: Int, n: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = ???
```

I would like also to return *all* exceptions thrown while retrying. So, I define new exception class `ExceptionsList` and require `retryFoo` to return `ExceptionsList` when all retries fail.

```
case class ExceptionsList(es: List[Exception]) extends Exception { ... }
```

How would you write `retryFoo` to retry `foo` and return a `Future` with either the `foo` result or `ExceptionsList` ?

Comment: Should the list of exceptions be returned only if method eventually fails? Or if, for example, retry limit is 5, and method succeeds on 3rd attempt should it return both result and exceptions from the first two failures?

Comment: Thanks, good question ! I wrote I need the exceptions only when _all_ retries fail. However it makes sense to return the previous exceptions even when the last retry succeeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
final case class ExceptionsList(es: List[Throwable]) extends Throwable
def retry[T](n: Int, expr: => Future[T], exs: List[Throwable] = Nil)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
  Future.unit.flatMap(_ => expr).recoverWith {
    case e if n > 0 => retry(n - 1, expr, e :: exs)
    case e => Future.failed(new ExceptionsList(e :: exs))
  }
```

`expr` is call-by-name since it itself could throw an exception rather than returning a failed Future. I keep the accumulated exceptions in a list, but I guess that's a taste-thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Future's `transformWith` and a little recursion to do the retrying. Using `transformWith` you can pattern match on the success or failure of your future.  In the success case, you just return the result of the `Success` and you're done since you don't care about intermediate failures.  On the failure case you make a recursive call where you decrement the retry count and append the exception to a list in your parameter list to keep track of all your failures.  If `n` is ever zero, you've exhausted your retries.  In this case you just create a new instance of `ExceptionsList` and fail the future.

The below example demonstrates the failure case when all futures throw exceptions.  You can call `retryFoo(3)` and you will get a failed future with three exceptions.

```
case class ExceptionsList(es: List[Throwable]) extends Exception

def retryFoo(n: Int, exceptions: List[Throwable] = List())(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = {
  if (n == 0) {
    Future.failed(ExceptionsList(exceptions))
  } else {
    Future {
      throw new Exception("fail!")
    }.transformWith {
      case Success(result) => Future(result)
      case Failure(ex) =>
        println("Retrying!")
        retryFoo(n - 1, exceptions :+ ex)
    }
  }
}
```