# Enable retries on the Scala function returning a Future

Tags: scala

I have some functions which return `Future`s. The callers register callbacks by `onComplete`.

```scala
def makeHttpRequest(): Future[T] = ???
makeHttpRequest().onComplete {
  case Success(v) => ???
  case Failure(ex) => ???
}
```

Now I want to enable retries on these functions (or function callings). Is there any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no retry capability out-of-the-box. However based on [Retry a function that returns a Future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033404/5205022) consider

```
def retry[T](n: Int, expr: => Future[T]): Future[T] =
  Future.unit.flatMap(_ => expr).recoverWith {
    case e if n > 1 => retry(n - 1, expr)
    case e => Future.failed(e)
  }

retry(3, makeHttpRequest())
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/otseSX0/0

or consider dedicated library such as [softwaremill/retry](https://github.com/softwaremill/retry).

Comment: in first case clausure you need to have `case e if n > 1` not `case e if n > 0` to retry 3 times instead of 4.

Comment: What if we want to wait for a while to make another attempt? `sleep` is not a great choice. Is there any other simple option? I'm using Akka/Scala, but don't want to reschedule the message to the actor.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeHttpRequest(maxRetryCount: Int, currentRetryCount: Int = 0): Future[T] = {
  val responseFuture = ???
  if (currentRetryCount == maxRetryCount)
    responseFuture
  else
    responseFuture.recoverWith(makeHttpRequest(maxRetryCount, currentRetryCount + 1))
}

makeHttpRequest(3).onComplete {
  case Success(v) => ???
  case Failure(ex) => ???
}
```